# pass perl variables to gnuplot

Tags: perl, gnuplot

I wrote a perl script to parse some files and get some data. Now I wanna use gnuplot to generate charts for these data. Can I pass the variables from perl to gnuplot?

By the way, since I don't have Chart::Graph in the system, I'm planning to use pipe, something like this

`open GP, '| gnuplot';`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;


open my $PROGRAM, '|-', 'gnuplot'
    or die "Couldn't pipe to gnuplot: $!";

say {$PROGRAM} 'set terminal postscript';
say {$PROGRAM} "set output 'plot.ps'";
say {$PROGRAM} "plot 'mydata.dat' using 1:2 title 'Column'";

close $PROGRAM;
```

The command:

```
set terminal postscript
```

sets up gnuplot to produce postscript output. To see the list of possible output formats type:

```
gnuplot> set terminal
```

The command:

```
set output 'plot.ps'
```

directs the output to the file plot.ps.

The command:

```
plot 'mydata.dat' using 1:2 title 'Column'
```

reads some data from the file `mydata.dat` and plots it.

To enter data on the command line, you specify "-" as the filename and use $ variables:

```
gnuplot> plot "-" using ($1):($2) with lines title 'My Line'
input data ('e' ends) > 1 2
input data ('e' ends) > 3 4
input data ('e' ends) > e
gnuplot>
```

So you can alter the perl program like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;

open my $PROGRAM, '|-', 'gnuplot'
    or die "Couldn't pipe to gnuplot: $!";

say {$PROGRAM} 'set terminal postscript';
say {$PROGRAM} "set output 'plot.ps'";
say {$PROGRAM} "plot '-' using (\$1):(\$2) with lines title 'My Line'";
print {$PROGRAM} "1 2\n3 4\ne\n";

close $PROGRAM;
```

To plot circles, you can do this:

```
gnuplot> set xrange [-2:5]    
gnuplot> set yrange[-2:5]     
gnuplot> plot "-" using ($1):($2):($3) with circles title 'My Circles'
input data ('e' ends) > 0 0 1     ****(x,y,radius)
input data ('e' ends) > 1 1 2
input data ('e' ends) > e
gnuplot>
```

Comment: I was actually thinking of passing an array to gnuplot, and the elements in the array can only be 0, 1 or 2. According to the value of each element, gnuplot either draws a rectangle, circle or triangle. I guess gnuplot isn't the best tool to do this, is it..?@7stud

Comment: It's not too onerous to have to write your data to a file.  You can use the tempfile module if needed.

Comment: But can I map "0, 1, 2" to "rectangle, circle, triangle" even if I write "0, 1, 2" to a file? @7stud

Comment: Why do you need gnuplot to do the mapping? What's the matter with perl? And I figured out how to enter data on the command line in gnuplot.

Comment: The system in my company does't have GD::Graph or Chart::Graph, and I can't install it, so I may need another tool. @7stud